# How can I change from custom paint widget to clip path widget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
class CoverPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Size sSize;
  const CoverPainter({this.sSize});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    final double r = (sSize.width).toDouble()/6.8;

    paint.color = Color(0xffE6E6E5);
    canvas.drawPath(
      Path.combine(
        PathOperation.difference,
        Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(sSize.width/2-r, 0.6*sSize.height-90-r, sSize.width/2+r, 0.6*sSize.height-90+r)),
        Path()
          ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
              center: Offset(sSize.width / 2, 1.2/2*sSize.height-90 ),
              radius: sSize.width/6.8))
          ..close(),
      ),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

this was my original code, and for some reasons, I need to change that to clip path widget.
and as a beginner, it is really hard...
(btw, sSize is screenSize, not a canvas size)

```
class CoverClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    //final path = Path();
    final double r = (size.width).toDouble()/6.8;

    Path.combine(
        PathOperation.difference,
        Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(size.width/2-r, 0.6*size.height-90-r, size.width/2+r, 0.6*size.height-90+r)),
        Path()
          ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
              center: Offset(size.width / 2, 1.2/2*size.height-90 ),
              radius: size.width/6.8))
          ..close()
    );
    return Path();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I tried that like this, but nothing happened.
there was no error but nothing showed.

```
class _Layer2State extends State<Layer2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = widget.size;

    // return CustomPaint(painter: CoverPainter(sSize: size));

    return ClipPath(
      clipper: CoverClipper(),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Actually, I don't know nothing about clippath.
I need help......

Comment: you're returning an empty Path() over: return Path();... you should return the one you created

Comment: I changed the code like this : return Path.combine(~~~);

Comment: and nothing happened too

Comment: if you write that comment as an answer, I will pick that for an answer of my question

Comment: done! and I also added an extra tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the actual Path you want to modify and it will work. The current path being returned is an empty one:

```
class CoverClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final double r = (size.width).toDouble()/6.8;

    return Path.combine(
        PathOperation.difference,
        Path()..addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(size.width/2-r, 0.6*size.height-90-r, size.width/2+r, 0.6*size.height-90+r)),
        Path()
          ..addOval(Rect.fromCircle(
              center: Offset(size.width / 2, 1.2/2*size.height-90 ),
              radius: size.width/6.8))
          ..close()
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true; // you can also change this to true to repaint.
  }
}
```